# How to convert YYYYMM to YYYY-MM datetime format without day?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have two datasets that have monthly frequencies. For one of them,`df`, I had to aggregate some data to turn it from daily to monthly using the following code:

```
df_grouped=df.groupby([df.index.to_period('M'),'City ID']).agg({'Estimated Population':'mean','Estimated Population_2019':'mean','Confirmed Rate':['mean','std'],'Death Rate':['mean','std'],'New Confirmed':'sum','New Deaths':'sum'})

df_grouped.index.rename(['Month','City ID'],inplace=True)
```

After doing these changes my dates became in the format `YYYY-MM`, for example:

```
2020-01
2020-02
...
2021-07
```

My other dataset, `df2`, has the date in format `YYYMM`, so I used the following code to convert it:

```
df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE'],format='%Y%m')
```

My new dates become in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, where all the `DD` become 01, as follows:

```
2020-01-01
2020-02-01
...
2021-07-01
```

How can I convert `df2` date now from `YYYY-MM-DD` to `YYYY-MM`?

I was thinking, maybe there is a way to convert straight from `YYYYMM` to `YYYY-MM`?

Comment: @Corralien I have updated the code to reflect the YYYY-MM change, the change was on the `index.month` part, I actually used `index.to_period('M')` when aggregating the dataset. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE'],format='%Y%m').dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
# or
df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str).str.replace(r'(\d{4})(\d{2})', r'\1-\2', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your column to `PeriodIndex`:

```
>>> pd.PeriodIndex(df2['DATE'], freq='M')
PeriodIndex(['2020-09', '2020-10', '2020-11', '2020-12', '2021-01', '2021-02'],
            dtype='period[M]', name='DATE')
```

Input data:

```
dti = pd.date_range('2020-9', '2021-3', freq='M')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': dti.strftime('%Y%m')})
print(df2)

# Output
     DATE
0  202009
1  202010
2  202011
3  202012
4  202101
5  202102
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01']})
pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('M')
```

Output:

[image]